# Mysql query with subquerys for each column with different categories

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE category (
idcategory INT, 
category VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE themes (
idtheme INT, 
idcategory INT, 
theme VARCHAR(50));
```

n numbers of categories. For this example, lets say 6.
Each category has 18 themes. No more or less.

I want to do a query that shows what themes are in the database for each category, something like:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   CATEGORY 1        |   CATEGORY 2        |   CATEGORY 3        |   CATEGORY 4        |   CATEGORY 5        |   CATEGORY 6        |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   CAT1 - THEME 1    |   CAT2 - THEME 1    |   CAT3 - THEME 1    |   CAT4 - THEME 1    |   CAT5 - THEME 1    |   CAT6 - THEME 1    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 2    |   CAT2 - THEME 2    |   CAT3 - THEME 2    |   CAT4 - THEME 2    |   CAT5 - THEME 2    |   CAT6 - THEME 2    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 3    |   CAT2 - THEME 3    |   CAT3 - THEME 3    |   CAT4 - THEME 3    |   CAT5 - THEME 3    |   CAT6 - THEME 3    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 4    |   CAT2 - THEME 4    |   CAT3 - THEME 4    |   CAT4 - THEME 4    |   CAT5 - THEME 4    |   CAT6 - THEME 4    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 5    |   CAT2 - THEME 5    |   CAT3 - THEME 5    |   CAT4 - THEME 5    |   CAT5 - THEME 5    |   CAT6 - THEME 5    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 6    |   CAT2 - THEME 6    |   CAT3 - THEME 6    |   CAT4 - THEME 6    |   CAT5 - THEME 6    |   CAT6 - THEME 6    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 7    |   CAT2 - THEME 7    |   CAT3 - THEME 7    |   CAT4 - THEME 7    |   CAT5 - THEME 7    |   CAT6 - THEME 7    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 8    |   CAT2 - THEME 8    |   CAT3 - THEME 8    |   CAT4 - THEME 8    |   CAT5 - THEME 8    |   CAT6 - THEME 8    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 9    |   CAT2 - THEME 9    |   CAT3 - THEME 9    |   CAT4 - THEME 9    |   CAT5 - THEME 9    |   CAT6 - THEME 9    |
|   CAT1 - THEME 10   |   CAT2 - THEME 10   |   CAT3 - THEME 10   |   CAT4 - THEME 10   |   CAT5 - THEME 10   |   CAT6 - THEME 10   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 11   |   CAT2 - THEME 11   |   CAT3 - THEME 11   |   CAT4 - THEME 11   |   CAT5 - THEME 11   |   CAT6 - THEME 11   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 12   |   CAT2 - THEME 12   |   CAT3 - THEME 12   |   CAT4 - THEME 12   |   CAT5 - THEME 12   |   CAT6 - THEME 12   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 13   |   CAT2 - THEME 13   |   CAT3 - THEME 13   |   CAT4 - THEME 13   |   CAT5 - THEME 13   |   CAT6 - THEME 13   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 14   |   CAT2 - THEME 14   |   CAT3 - THEME 14   |   CAT4 - THEME 14   |   CAT5 - THEME 14   |   CAT6 - THEME 14   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 15   |   CAT2 - THEME 15   |   CAT3 - THEME 15   |   CAT4 - THEME 15   |   CAT5 - THEME 15   |   CAT6 - THEME 15   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 16   |   CAT2 - THEME 16   |   CAT3 - THEME 16   |   CAT4 - THEME 16   |   CAT5 - THEME 16   |   CAT6 - THEME 16   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 17   |   CAT2 - THEME 17   |   CAT3 - THEME 17   |   CAT4 - THEME 17   |   CAT5 - THEME 17   |   CAT6 - THEME 17   |
|   CAT1 - THEME 18   |   CAT2 - THEME 18   |   CAT3 - THEME 18   |   CAT4 - THEME 18   |   CAT5 - THEME 18   |   CAT6 - THEME 18   |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So, each column is a category and the rows are the different themes.
Each category it's independant of each other and so does Themes except for those being of the same category.

I have been struggling with this for hours. Maybe I am getting old or exhausted.

any ideas of how to approach this query?

Comment: `how to approach this query` sounds like a SQL question only. No relation to `PHP`, `HTML`, nor `html-table`. Please review your tags and only use appropriate ones.

Comment: you want it in a single or multiple query ? and how do you want to display. if its not in html table then, I feel you can easily display this.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation, if you know exactly what categories you have:

```
select max(case when categoryid = 1 then theme end) as cat1,
       max(case when categoryid = 2 then theme end) as cat2,
       . . .
from (select th.*,
             row_number() over (partition by th.idcategory order by th.idtheme) as seqnum
      from themes th
     ) th
group by seqnum;
```

Repeat the logic for each column you want in the result set.